# RuntimeError: _th_exp_out not supported on CUDAType for Long

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

### Questions and Help

I'm trying to finetune a transformer model for question answering, and am using the BCEWithLogitsLoss function.
However when I try calculating loss i get this error:

> RuntimeError: _th_exp_out not supported on CUDAType for Long

I'm inputting matrices with the shape and dtype of `[16, 2]` and `Long`
Bud sadly I've no idea to solve this. I tried using another dtype (int32, float32, double), which didn't work.

Here is the code:

```py
def loss_fn(self, preds, labels):
    return torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(preds, labels)

def train_fn(self, dataloader, model, optimizer, device):
    # Some other stuff here
    pred = model(
            token_ids = token_ids,
            attention_mask = attention_mask,
            token_type_ids = token_type_ids)
    start_scores = torch.argmax(pred[0], dim=1)
    end_scores = torch.argmax(pred[1], dim=1)
        
    pred = torch.tensor(list(zip(start_scores, end_scores)))
    pred = pred.to(device, dtype=torch.long)

    batch_loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing both, pred and label as float worked in my case.